# How to apply my changes to an application that is generated from a template on a Github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello dear Rails developers, the question I'm going to ask here might seem rookie to Rails experts, but I'm sadly stuck and need directions from you.

I'm trying to make some local changes to a Ruby on Rails application that I created/generated with the following command:

`rails new app-name -m https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harvard-library/spotlight/log_entries/template.rb`

as instructed on the open source code base: https://github.com/harvard-library/spotlight/tree/log_entries

The changes I intended to make, is adding JSON format support to the `show` function in `PageController` at the following file:
https://github.com/harvard-library/spotlight/blob/log_entries/app/controllers/spotlight/pages_controller.rb

The created/generate `app-name` RoR application, however, doesn't even have the `pages_controller.rb` file in its directories.

There my question arise: How do I make changes to the functionalities of an application that is created/generated with `rails new -m <template>` option? How does the template created application relate to the code base itself?

Thank you for reading this and I look forward to your advice.

Comment: Hey Hao, Welcome to SO. Here is the `pages_controller.rb` file: https://github.com/harvard-library/spotlight/blob/log_entries/app/controllers/spotlight/pages_controller.rb

Comment: Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**How do I make changes to the functionalities of an application that is created/generated with rails new -m  option?**

This is no different than the application generated from scratch.

**How does the template create application relate to the code base itself?**
The Answer is when you provide `template.rb` to `rails` it starts executing each line as a command. more like the way it gets executed on the terminal and thats basically the steps to build any rails app from scratch. you can read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html

Also, check-out how `bin/setup` works in rails and this may help you understand the `template.rb` part because they both follow pretty much the same principle. for reference: https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/07/08/quick-setup-for-your-rails-apps